# Elb healthcheck fails for Https

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Im using a url for ELB healthcheck in AWS.

This health check is working with

```
Http:1140/<myurltoapplication>
```

and the attached Ec2 Instance were showing as Inservice

but when i use

```
Https:11402/<myurltoapplication>
```

the healthcheck fails and the attached Ec2 instances were showing OutofService.

Not able to figure out the issue.Please help!!

After executing the curl command

```
curl -kv https://<ip>:11402/<myurl>
```

im getting below response

```
 About to connect() to <ip> port 11402 (#0)
*   Trying <ip> connected
* Connected to <ip> (<ip>) port 11402 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: *****
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
```

and i tried

```
curl -I <ip>:11402/<myurl>
```

as mentioned below

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html
```

it doesnt return any result

Comment: What does `curl -kv https://<ec2-instance-ip-address>:11402/<myurltoapplication>` show?

Comment: About to connect() to <ip> port 11402 (#0)
*   Trying <ip> connected
* Connected to <ip> (<ip>) port 11402 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: *****
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost

Comment: You might edit your post to include that `curl` command, and the full result, for other reads, rather than having it in the comments.

Comment: @Castaglia updated my answer

Comment: Hrm; you mentioned `curl -I`, but I was hoping you'd use `curl -kv`; the `-kv` command-line options are more verbose about issues such as SSL/TLS issues; that's why including the full response/output from `curl` is best for debugging issues like this.

Comment: @Castaglia No I have tried both please see my updated question

Comment: If `curl` isn't working then your issue has nothing to do with ELB.